# Compare h:i:s to see which hour is greater including midnight - PHP

Tags: php

Okay so I have a function that compares the hours from `00:00:00 - 24:00:00` to tell the closing time.  Now the issue I have is, lets say the store opens at 8AM and closes at midnight, well `00:00:00`is going to be less than `23:00:00`. How would I go about making sure that it recognizes that midnight is greater?

Here is what I am doing:

```
if((strtotime($openTime) < time()) && (strtotime($closeTime) > time()))
{
    $response['data_retrieved']['store'][$i]['store_settings']['open'] = 1;// open
}
else
{
    $response['data_retrieved']['store'][$i]['store_settings']['open'] = 0; //close
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `24:00:00`, you'll need the full date string `Y-m-d H:i:s` to do an accurate comparison.

Even just adding in the date won't be enough, as it will break when looking at the last day of the month (`'31 08:00:00' < '1 00:00:00'`).

Comment: Thanks, wasnt sure if I needed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a very good [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) support. Its better to use that instead of reinventing things. Also like @mopo922 suggested, you'll need the full `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 0):

The answer @mopo922 provided above is the most foolproof and most correct answer.

Another method would be to "add" 24 hours to the $closeTime if $startTime > $closeTime. It's quite dodgy but still solves the problem.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

$openTime = strtotime('08:00');
$currentTime = strtotime('23:00');
$closeTime = strtotime('10:00');

echo 'open: ' .$openTime . '<br>' .
     'time(): ' . $currentTime . '<br>' .
     'close: ' . $closeTime . '<br>';

// 1 day = 86400 seconds
if ($closeTime < $openTime) {
    $closeTime += 86400;
}

if($openTime < $currentTime && $closeTime > $currentTime)
{
    echo 'open';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'closed';
}
?>
```